# Is there a way to import multiple page PDF's in a PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to import 14 pdf files into a powerpoint every day for a daily meeting. I have successfully imported the PDF's using VBA but it only imports the first page. Some of my pdfs will have multiple pages.

The pdf's are all generated out of a access database and need to be in pdf form because they are also sent to people at other locations. The powerpoint is solely for our team.

```vb
Public Function Import_Reports()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim fpath As String
Dim fname As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim PotentialDate As Long
Dim Free As Boolean
Dim sldCount As Integer

sldCount = 1
fpath = "K:\Dept\Erie-Eng\Erie\ZSPEC\application engineering\Zurn Application Engineering Project Management\Gemba Files\" & Format(Now, "yyyy") & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm") & "\"

PotentialDate = Format(Date, "0,###.0000") - 1
'MsgBox fpath & Format(PotentialDate, "yyyy_mm_dd")
Do Until Free = True
    If Len(Dir(fpath & Format(PotentialDate, "yyyy_mm_dd"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        PotentialDate = DateAdd("d", -1, PotentialDate)
        'MsgBox fpath & Format(PotentialDate, "yyyy_mm_dd")
    Else
        Free = True
        fpath = fpath & Format(PotentialDate, "yyyy_mm_dd") & "\"
    End If
Loop

strFileSpec = fpath & "*.pdf*"
'MsgBox strFileSpec
fname = Dir(strFileSpec, vbDirectory)
'MsgBox fname
Do While Len(fname) > 0
On Error GoTo mkslide

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(sldCount)
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, 11# * 72, 8.5 * 72, , fpath & fname, msoFalse, , , , msoFalse)
fname = Dir
sldCount = sldCount + 1
Loop
Exit Function
mkslide:
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout)
Resume Next
End Function
```

I am needing to be able to pull in the additional pdf pages and also insert each of them into their own slides.

Comment: It's possible if you have a full version of Acrobat installed. Then you can use a VBA solution like Kenneth Hobson's answer: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1157046-split-pdf-file-into-individual-pages-using-vba-print.html

Comment: John, for real man I have been looking for something for hours. This will work! I'll just have to have it redelete the page by page files after! Thank you!